# Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets error : Unhandled Exception: OutOfMemoryException while creating docker image

Tags: c#, msbuild, dockerfile, .net-4.8

I am getting Microsoft.Net.Compilers.3.3.1\tools\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(52,5): error : Unhandled Exception: OutOfMemoryException
while executing msbuild step inside dockerfile, but it runs fine if I run the same step in command prompt

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./


RUN dotnet restore ./Internal.Api.csproj -s "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" 

RUN msbuild Internal.Api.csproj /v:diag /p:Configuration=Release -r:False 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY --from=build /app/Internal.Api/. ./

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Internal.Api.dll"]
```

[image]

How should I get more details or solutions about it?

Answer (score 0):

believe it is due to the parameter /p:Platform=AnyCPU by default, try to add it to your build

```
RUN msbuild Internal.Api.csproj /v:diag /p:Configuration=Release -r:False /p:Platform=x64
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).